# Drupal 6: in hook_cron, how do I specify the path to a module file?

Tags: drupal-6, drupal-modules

In my .module file, I have an basic implementation of hook_cron:

```
function foobar_cron()
{
    $file = fopen('my_file', 'a');
    // stuff
    fclose($file);
}
```

The problem is that this method is called by (http://www.example.com/)cron.php, so the path my_file is incorrect. **How do I specify the correct path for my_file which is located in the foobar module directory?**

Answer (score 3):

```
<?php
   // something like the following. Might need to tweak the pathing.
   $path = drupal_get_path('module', $module_name) . '/my_file'; // $module_name = foobar in your case 
?>
```

Comment: umm, depending on how your server is configured that should return a string path like _/sites/all/modules/foobar/myfile_ so yes, relative to htdocs. So you can modify it and manually do something like: _$path = '/var/wwww/htdocs' . drupal_get_path('module', 'foobar'). '/my_file'; $file = fopen($path, 'a'); That should work?

Comment: It does, but that is exactly what you want because the current directory for Drupal is always the top level directory, as all requests go through index.php, cron.php or update.php. So it is safet to directly use $path. Drupal itself is doing the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that you can use following code to access files in your module's directory when implementing hook_cron():

```
function foobar_cron()
{
        $file = fopen(realpath(".") . PATH_SEPARATOR . drupal_get_path('module', 'foobar') . PATH_SEPARATOR . 'myfile.txt', 'a');
}
```

PATH_SEPARATOR makes sure the path also works on Windows.

Comment: PATH_SEPARATOR is either ":" or ";", *not* /. What you meant is DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR. Also, it is quite safe to simply use / because that works always, including Windows.